# SQL query to calculate a value from 3 different rows

Tags: sql

```
col1       col2       cal_val

F          1879       1879
%          25         1409
$          -45        1454
```

First row basically outputs back the entry in column 2
2nd row would basically calculate 25% of the value in row1, column 3 and then subtract that value from previous value which is 1879-470 = 1409

I need to be able to calculate final value of 1454 (which is basically a subtraction from the 2nd row output value)1409 - (-45) which would equal to 1454

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select ( (sum(case when col1 = 'F' then col2 end) *
          sum(case when col1 = '%' then 1 - col2 / 100.0 end)
         ) -
         sum(case when col1 = '$' then col2 end)
       )
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3aaba02cb094a85cf29ac114ae5ae816) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice at SQL.. It doesn't calculate the final value which would need to subtract from the output in row2's output value

Comment: Noah it. works , i tired it  on Postgress

Comment: Would it matter if it is Oracle ?. I have tried it in Oracle, I am getting a null output

Comment: Noah. check if you have nulls in your recordsets, it. may. cause some problems if yes then just set  defaults  ```ISNULL(expression, replacement)``` or which syntactic you are using

Comment: @Noah . . . You would only get `NULL` if the original values are `NULL` or if the rows are missing.  Your question doesn't specify what to do in that case.  In fact, the arithmetic you describe returns `NULL` if any values are missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
create temporary table t_teble 
(
col1   text ,

col2   numeric ,

cal_val numeric );


insert into t_teble
select 'F',1879, 1879 union all
select '%',25,1409 union all
select '$',-45,1454;

select ( (sum(case when col1 = 'F' then col2 end) *
          sum(case when col1 = '%' then 1 - col2 / 100.0 end)
         ) -
         sum(case when col1 = '$' then col2 end)
       ), 
       (sum(case when col1 = 'F' then col2 end) *
          sum(case when col1 = '%' then 1 - col2 / 100.0 end)
         )
from t_teble;
```